# Hapi with Bell failed to authenticate to Twitter

Tags: typescript, twitter, twitter-oauth, hapi.js

I have build some basic backend api require multiple authentication. Now I'm trying to connect to Twitter API using Bell, but the problem is instead of displaying the page to let me authenticate the App it show error **{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}**

Below is the dependency files:

## index.ts

```
'use strict';

import * as hapi from "hapi";
import * as boom from "boom";
import router from './router/router';

const server: hapi.Server = new hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

// .register(...) registers a module within the instance of the API. The callback is then used to tell that the loaded module will be used as an authentication strategy. 
server.register( [require( 'hapi-auth-jwt' ), require('hapi-auth-cookie'), require('bell')], ( err ) => {

    // normal server auth strategy using JWT
    server.auth.strategy( 'token', 'jwt', {  
        key: 'secretkey',
        verifyOptions: {
            algorithms: [ 'HS256' ],
        },
        redirectTo: '/login'
    } );

    //Setup the session strategy
    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
        password: 'secret_cookie_encryption_password', //Use something more secure in production
        redirectTo: '/login', //If there is no session, redirect here
        isSecure: false //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
    });

  //Setup the social Twitter login strategy
    server.auth.strategy('twitter', 'bell', {
        provider: 'twitter',
        password: 'secret_cookie_encryption_password', //Use something more secure in production
        clientId: 'secretkey',
        clientSecret: ' secretkey',
        isSecure: false //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
    });

    //server.auth.default('token');

    // Make sure server get auth first before attach the router
    router.forEach( ( router ) => {
        console.log( `attaching ${ router.path }` );
        server.route( router );
    } );

} );



server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

## router.ts

```
'use strict';

import controllers from '../server/controllers/Index';
import models from '../server/models/index';
import { compareHashPassword } from '../Helper';
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import * as Boom from "boom";

// Init express router saja
let router;
let User = models.User;

// Setting API URL
router = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
          auth: {
            strategies: ['token', 'session'],        
        }, //<-- require a session for this, so we have access to the twitter profile
          handler: function(request, reply) {

            //Return a message using the information from the session
            return reply('Hello, ' + request.auth.credentials.displayName + '!');
          }
        }
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/login',
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            return reply('Please Login to ReviewUr!');
        }
    },
    // Authentication route for Token
    {
        path: '/auth',
        method: 'POST',
        handler: controllers.Auths.list
    },
    // Authentication route for Twitter
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/auth/twitter',
        config: {
          auth: 'twitter',
          handler: function(request, reply) {

            if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
              //return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Authentication failed: ' + request.auth.error.message));
                return reply('unauthorized!');
            }


            const profile = request.auth.credentials.profile;

            request.cookieAuth.set({
              twitterId: profile.id,
              username: profile.username,
              displayName: profile.displayName
            });

            return reply.redirect('/').catch(error => reply(error));
          }
        }
    },
   ///////////////////////////////////////
];

export default router
```

is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with moving '/auth/twitter' route to over '/auth', it seems it handles '/auth' before '/auth/twitter'. 
In which route are you trying to show the user sign-in options? /login ?

Did you try without jwt or auth-cookie, just bell with twitter? Maybe something wrong with other plugins.

This is my implementation which I've extracted from a live app.

**app-auth.js**

```
const Boom = require('boom');
const internals = {};
const config = require('config');

exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
    server.auth.scheme('basic', internals.implementation);
    server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', true);

    // handle twitter login errors here
    server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
        const req = request.response;
        if (req.isBoom && request.path === 'login') {
            // there has been an error occurred during login process, sent user to home page
            server.log(['error', 'auth', 'twitter'], req.output.payload.error);
            return reply.redirect('/?error=103&account_error=' + encodeURIComponent(req.output.payload.error));
        }

        return reply.continue();
    });

    // twitter application registration
    server.auth.strategy('twitter', 'bell', {
        provider: 'twitter',
        password: config.get('twitter.pass'),
        clientId: config.get('twitter.key'),
        clientSecret: config.get('twitter.secret'),
        isSecure: config.get('authSecurity')
    });

    return next();
};

internals.implementation = function (server, options) {

    return {
        authenticate: function (request, reply) {
            // if there is no session information
            if (!request.yar.get('auth')) {
                const headers = request.headers;
                // if this request is xmlhttp then return as json
                if (headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
                    return reply(Boom.unauthorized("Please sign-in to system."));
                }
                return reply.redirect('/login');
            }
            return reply.continue({credentials: request.yar.get('auth')});
        }
    }
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'app_auth',    
    version: require('../package.json').version
};
```

**twitter-route.js**

```
exports.view = {
    description: 'Twitter authentication handler',
    auth: 'twitter',
    handler: async (request, reply) => {
        // something went wrong
        if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            request.yar.flash('ERROR', request.auth.error.message);
            return reply.redirect('/login_error?error=103&account_error=' + encodeURIComponent(request.auth.error.message));
        }

        // profile information coming from twitter
        const profile = request.auth.credentials.profile;

        // do what ever you want with profile

    }
};
```